# Defining a function that takes a std::array as a parameter

Tags: c++, arrays

Basic question here, with (hopefully) a simple answer: I'm trying to write a function whose first argument is a std::array, but with an arbitrary size.

```
void f(array<int> x) {
    //do stuff
}
```

isn't valid, because I need a size for `array<int, #>`.  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Please pay particular attention to this section http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810672/2296458

Comment: @Cyber no, that is not a duplicate... did you even read the linked question and answer? The linked question is about C style arrays.

Comment: Do you know the size of the array at compile time?

Comment: @CSGregorian then go with [Quentin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24682833/1941161)'s answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way is to make `f` a function template :

```
template <size_t N>
void f(array<int, N> x) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 12):

*[Quentins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682805/defining-a-function-that-takes-a-stdarray-as-a-parameter/24682833#24682833)* is correct if you do not need to be flexible at run-time.

However, if you need to be flexible at run-time I would recommend you to use an `std::vector` instead.

```
void f(vector<int> x) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Also, you might want to use a reference or `const` reference to avoid the copying of the array or vector, at least if you do not need the copy.

Answer (score 5):

A second way around it, is using the function template (@Quentin) and delegate to a non template function:

```
#include <array>

void g(int* first, int* last) {
    //do stuff
}

template <size_t N>
inline void f(std::array<int, N> x) {
    g(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

Comment: And what is the concrete benefit of the non template function?

Comment: @Theolodis: The implementation can be in a source file.

Comment: @Theolodis _'And what is the concrete benefit ...?'_ The non template function is a bit more generic, and no longer depends on the compile time provided `size_t N`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok, I didn't think of that... Actually it could even be used with the vector solution I proposed too.

Comment: @Theolodis _'Actually it could even be used with the vector solution ...'_ Yup, exactly. You've got the point. The `std::vector` variant could be even a specialization for `N=0` or so.

Comment: Or you could just call `g()` directly without bothering with `f()`. :)